# problem dynamically changing the form's state

Tags: reactjs

I have an array inside **values** and I would like to change state using the "name" property inside the form but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
const initialFlashcardState = {
  collection_name: '',
  prompt: '',
  answers: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
  right_answer: 1,
};

const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFlashcardState);

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value,
  });
};

return (
  <Controls.Input
    label='First Answer'
    name='answers[0]'
    value={values.answers[0]}
    onChange={handleInputChange}
  />
);
```

Comment: The problem is that you are setting the value of the property `answers[0]` which is not in the state. What is your goal?

Comment: i want to modify the first index in the array `answers` changing `'1'` to something else. @LucaPizzini

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to change property called answers[0] and that is a string.
here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glade-um03f?file=/src/App.js)

although it is not the best approach to this it's better to use an object array for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your data structure I would suggest to pass index to handleInputChange as long as your inputs are ordered:

```js
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    setValues({
        ...values,
        answers: [
          ...values.answers.slice(0, index),
          value,
          ...values.answers.slice(index + 1)
    })
}

/* ... */

<Controls.Input
  label="First Answer"
  value={values.answers[0]}
  onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, 0)}
/>
```